# Saving data using added dataset in asp.net

Tags: vb.net

I have added a dataset from New Item >> DataSet and configured it.
I want to add new row to it using

Dim drNewRow as datarow=DataSet1.tblTest.New

but when I press . after DataSet1, IntelliSense does not catch tblTest, rather it gives tblTestRow and tblTestDataTable

How to get DataSet1.tblTest here?
Thanks

Comment: Create an instance of DataSet1(e.g. `yourDataSet1`), then you can use TableTestTableAdapter to fill `yourDataSet1.TableTest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an instance of `DataSet1`, then you can use an insance of `TableTestTableAdapter` to fill yourDataSet1.TableTest

```
Dim ds = New DataSet1()
Dim da = New DataSet1TableAdapters.TableTestTableAdapter()
da.Fill(ds.TableTest)
' now you can loop all DataRows of the DataTable '
For Each dr As DataSet1.TableTestRow In ds.TableTest.Rows
    ' if your DataTable contains a DataColumn with name TableTestID '
    Dim id As Int32 = dr.TableTestID
Next
```